# splist add item rights and splist update with workflow problem

Tags: permissions

i have an interesting problem here.

My users are only able to add new items to splist.
But the same splist has a automatic workflow which updates a field after a new item is created.but as he/she doesn't has rights to update the wf fails on update.
i get the error "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information." and right of this it says Access denied..

is it because the workflow starts automatically with the user who creates the item and he/she doesn't have right to update it?
How can i find a solution on that,is there a way to start wfs with administrator by default. (created by sp designer)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the owner of a workflow with SP Designer...

You could replace your buil-in workflow with a custom coded one, that would do the RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate) to run the action with the WebApp Context.

Sorry for the code version, but I think it is the only way to make it happen that way.